# Change FROM and REPLYTO address in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i can't send email with user address as FROM and Reply To

In the FormRequest :

```
    public function persist()
{
    $reservation = Resa::create(
        $this->only(['nom', 'email', 'phone', 'formule', 'date_arr', 'date_ret', 'nb_adu', 'nb_enf', 'lemessage'])
    );
    Mail::to('contact@cotiga.fr')
    ->from($reservation->email, $reservation->nom)
    ->replyTo($reservation->email, $reservation->nom)
    ->send(new Reservation($reservation));

}
```

I have the error :

```
FatalThrowableError in ReservationForm.php line 48:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::from()
```

I tried full of possibility, but I can not change the field FROM and REPLYTO
Can you help me ?
Thank's

Answer (score 10):

The `Mail` Facade does not implement the `replyTo()` method anymore. Instead this method has moved to the `Mailable` class itself. Official documentation proposes to use the `build()` method  to setup the Mailable, however this is not always convenient (eg the replyTo field might be different each time)

However if you still want to use a similar syntax you can use:

```
$mailable = new myMailableClass;
$mailable->replyTo('reply@to.com');

Mail::to('email@tocom')
  ->send($mailable);
```

For a complete list of available methods on the Mailable class see the [Mailable Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.html)

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 5.4 Mailables, the `replyTo`, `subject`, `cc`, `bcc` and others can be set inside the mailable in the `build` method. This is also true for the `to` which can also be set on the Mail facade.

Here is a simple example of a contact form mailable using an array of attributes:

You may use the `to` static method directly on the `Mail` facade, but as an example, we're going to set it inside the mailable:

```
Mail::send(new ContactCompany($attributes));
```

Then set the `replyTo` inside the `build` method:

```
class ContactCompany extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $attributes;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $attributes
     */
    public function __construct($attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->to($this->attributes['departmentEmail'], config('app.name'));
        $this->replyTo($this->attributes['email'], $this->attributes['name']);
        $this->subject(sprintf("New contact message from %s", $this->attributes['name']));

        return $this->markdown('emails.contact.company');
    }
}
```

Please, note that `Mail::alwaysFrom()` and `Mail::alwaysReplyTo()` can be used before `Mail::send()` to set the `from` and `replyTo` of ***all*** emails, so make sure to use them with care.

Comment: When you set `replyTo`, `subject`, etc. inside `build` method, you won't be able to test that these values are set (`build` method is never called on mocked emails). It's better to move it to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method of sending emails are now [mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-mailables) and you can set from and reply to using from() or replyTo() methods.

However using plain `Mail` facades you should try to use `alwaysFrom` and `alwaysReplyTo` methods. However after sending such e-mail you should set again previous values to be sure no other emails will be impacted by this change.

But looking at method names it might be not the best solution so better is to look at mailables and use them to send e-mails in latest Laravel releases.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
I edit app>Mail>Reservation.php

```
    public function build()
    {
//      return $this->markdown('emails.reservation-email');
        return $this->from($this->reservation->email)->markdown('emails.reservation-email');
    }
```

app>Http>Request>ReservationForm.php

```
public function persist()
{
    $reservation = Resa::create(
        $this->only(['nom', 'email', 'phone', 'formule', 'date_arr', 'date_ret', 'nb_adu', 'nb_enf', 'lemessage'])
    );
    Mail::to('contact@cotiga.fr')->send(new Reservation($reservation));
}
```